# Travelling salesman (TSP) skip city

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to solve a problem which similar to traveling sales man problem but in this case the sales person can skip the city if the cost of visiting the city is too high.

Please give me some direction on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: You have a better chance to get a good answer at either http://math.stackexchange.com or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

One way, would be to copy/paste [this vehicle routing example](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-planner/blob/master/drools-planner-examples/src/main/resources/org/drools/planner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl) of [Drools Planner](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html) and hack it like this:

There are 2 Vehicles: 1 real Vehicle (= the tour) and 1 unused Vehicle (= the non used cities).
Customer == city. Remove the capacity rule.

Then, change the score rules so it only sums the distances of the cities (= customers) of the used vehicle (and not the unused vehicle):

```
rule "distanceToPreviousAppearance"
    when
        $customer : VrpCustomer(previousAppearance != null, $distanceToPreviousAppearance : distanceToPreviousAppearance, vehicleIsUsed == true)
    then
        insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("distanceToPreviousAppearance", ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_SOFT,
                $distanceToPreviousAppearance,
                $customer));
end

rule "distanceFromLastCustomerToDepot"
    when
        $customer : VrpCustomer(previousAppearance != null, vehicleIsUsed == true)
        not VrpCustomer(previousAppearance == $customer)
    then
        VrpVehicle vehicle = $customer.getVehicle();
        insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("distanceFromLastCustomerToDepot", ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_SOFT,
                $customer.getDistanceTo(vehicle),
                $customer));
end
```

Similarly, you can add a rule that sums the visiting bonus of every city visited by the used vehicle, and try to maximize that with ConstraintType.POSITIVE_SOFT (weighted vs the distance traveled).

Of course, you shouldn't just hack it like this: this is just the gist. Instead, rename and redesign it for your requirements.